# Creating a dictionary from a .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a .txt file with list of users, it goes like this:

```
ID - NAME(S) - LAST NAME(S) - LOGIN - PASSWORD

0001 - Juan Carlos - Botero Mora - jcboterom - snf23jn4

.

.
```

So, I need to create a dictionary like this:

```
{'0001': ['Juan Carlos', 'Botero Mora', 'jcboterom', 'snf23jn4']}
```

The code is

```
def dict():
with open('admins.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        if line.strip():
            key, value = line.split(None, 1)
            answer[key] = value.split()
return answer
```

But this is what I get:

```
{'0001': ['-', 'Juan', 'Carlos', '-', 'Botero', 'Mora', '-', 'jcboterom', '-', 'snf23jn4']
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are splitting your strings at all whiteplaces , which is what `str.split()` does. Instead you should split them at `'-'` and then strip off the whitespace from the result.

Code -

```
def dict():
    with open('admins.txt', 'r') as document:
        answer = {}
        for line in document:
            if line.strip():
                key, value = line.split('-', 1)
                answer[key.strip()] = [v.strip() for v in value.split('-')]
    return answer
```

Demo -

```
>>> s = '0001 - Juan Carlos - Botero Mora - jcboterom - snf23jn4'
>>> key,value = s.split('-',1)
>>> answer = {}
>>> answer[key.strip()] = [v.strip() for v in value.split('-')]
>>> answer
{'0001': ['Juan Carlos', 'Botero Mora', 'jcboterom', 'snf23jn4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to split the `value` again with the delimiter `-` rather than space.

```
>>> key, value = line.split('-', 1)
>>> answer[key] = value.split(' - ')
>>> answer
{'0001 ': [' Juan Carlos', 'Botero Mora', 'jcboterom', 'snf23jn4']}
```

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])` Return a list of the words in the string,
>   using sep as the delimiter string.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` can go with pattern. Here you can use `' - '`

```
>>> s = '0001 - Juan Carlos - Botero Mora - jcboterom - snf23jn4'
>>> s
'0001 - Juan Carlos - Botero Mora - jcboterom - snf23jn4'
>>> [key, value] = s.split(' - ', 1)
>>> key
'0001'
>>> value
'Juan Carlos - Botero Mora - jcboterom - snf23jn4'
>>> value = value.split(' - ')
>>> value
['Juan Carlos', 'Botero Mora', 'jcboterom', 'snf23jn4']
```